# Implementing launch screen for android with Delphi/Firemonkey

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

reading the https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time about the right way to implement a launch screen they say to create a Launcher style

```
<activity ...
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher" />
```

and they say that the easiest way to transition back to your normal theme is to call setTheme(R.style.AppTheme) before calling super.onCreate() and setContentView():

```
KOTLIN
JAVA
public class MyMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Make sure this is before calling super.onCreate
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_MyApp);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...
  }
}
```

problem is with delphi, when/where can I call `setTheme(R.style.Theme_MyApp);` ? from inside the form create it's not work so seam already too late, and even just after Application.Initialize it's seam to not work either :(

Comment: The question should be _how_ do you call `setTheme(R.style.Theme_MyApp)` since R is not available to a Delphi Android developer.

Comment: @nolaspeaker R is available to delphi android developer but it's need a little work. see some examples in demo of https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe

Comment: Ok, well I'll check that out @loki, but you can't extend an Android class in Delphi except by pre-compiling to jar file and then linking that in with your project. Ive done this with a boot receiver per that (now old) Dany Wind article, but not with any other Java class. I guess you have to weigh up the benefit here, against the effort required to achieve this.

Comment: @nolaspeaker exaclty , it's quite complicate to rebuild the jar :( I was thinking maybe i miss one even that the jar fire before the create that I can catch

Comment: You should look for how to create a `Splash screen` for Delphi Android application and you will find many articles around the web. Also newer versions of Delphi provide builtin ability to show splash image at your application start. While this option is by default enabled in a new project it is possible that if you have imported your project from older Delphi this option is disabled. So check your `Project Options-.>Application->Icons` to se if `include splash image` is checked.